# How does Event Binding work with passed in value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to event binding, and I cannot understand why and how a value is passed in `()` and its value is loaded. I am following Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#style-the-heroes) which part

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
```

where

```
selectedHero: Hero;

onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

I cannot understand where did the (hero) came from and know how to load which data

Answer (score 1):

The `hero` object came from the `*ngFor="let hero of heroes"`.

**ngFor directive:** is a way of repeating a template by using each item of an iterable as that template's context.

Every loop of heroes will use a specific `hero` object and will create a `li` element that will bind an onClick event using `(click)="onSelect(hero)"`.

As you can see, `onSelect` method was declared in your component as `onSelect(hero: Hero): void` this declaration allows you to use it in any place within the component's selector.

On the other hand, `heroes` object is an Array of type `hero` and will be loaded previously within your component.

Probably, that Array was loaded calling a specific service to load `heroes` and it's one of the first thing that every component must do for loading the necessary data that will be rendered.

**In component `HeroesComponent` the data regarding `heroes` was declared as follow:**

```
heroes = HEROES;
```

In that tutorial, the `heroes` data is provided by this file `mock-heroes.ts` and its content is the following:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this code I can assume that this component is implemented in a class that has an array called `heroes`. Most likely in your component's template there is a list, e.g. `<ul>`. The `*ngFor` directive iterates through the array `heroes` and creates one `<li>` element for each array element. The variable `hero` is just used to iterate through the array and you could have named it anything.

After the loop is complete, each `<li>`'s value is one instance of `Hero` from the array, and each `<li>` has a click listener. When you click on a list element (`<li>`), the method `onClick` is invoked passing whatever hero instance was assigned to this list element during the loop.